# Python splitting unknown string by spaces and parentheses

Tags: python, string, split

If I have a string that may be:

```
'Hello (Test1 test2) (Hello1 hello2) other_stuff'
```

I would like to split it into something like this:

```
split1='hello'
split2='Test1, test2'
split3='Hello1, hello2'
split4='other_stuff'
```

and then I will be putting it into one variable:

```
full_split=[split1, split2, split3, split4]
```

And also, the unknown string would be if they keep adding words to the end it would keep adding a split variable (`split5`, `split6`)

I am looking into regex but I don't like importing moduels that don't come with python. If I have to I will.

Comment: `I am looking into regex but I don't like importing moduels that don't come with python` - Python includes the `re` module that does regular expressions - (unless you're confusing it with the 3rd party enhanced lib called `regex`)

Comment: Ya, whoops. I just saw regex pop up while I was searching and thought it would be `import regex`. Thank you.

Comment: What should happen if "other stuff" had a space instead of underscore?

Comment: Just as Ashwini's answer would do. If it was `other stuff` then it would save it into the final string as "other" and then "stuff" (Completely separating the last words).

Comment: It would put `'other, stuff'` in the result as one string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `regex`, `str.split` and `str.join`:

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = "Hello (Test1 test2) (Hello1 hello2) other_stuff"
>>> [", ".join(x.split()) for x in re.split(r'[()]',strs) if x.strip()]
['Hello', 'Test1, test2', 'Hello1, hello2', 'other_stuff']
```

Comment: @TrevorPeyton only the first one?

Comment: Ya, in my example it would be (Test1 test2) and then the second one would be (Hello1 hello2). I got it though, I'm just going to remove the commas from the first one thus leaving the original string.

Answer (score 4):

There is an `re` module in the standard library. You could do something like this :

```
>>> s="Hello (Test1 test2) (Hello1 hello2) other_stuff"
>>> re.findall(r'\w+|\(\w+\s+\w+\)', s)
['Hello', '(Test1 test2)', '(Hello1 hello2)', 'other_stuff']
```

In fact, this depends very much on what your input looks like (spaces? other parentheses?), so you may need to adapt it to your case.

Answer (score 0):

This is working, and delete empty strings

```
import re, itertools
strs = 'Hello (Test1 test2) (Hello1 hello2) other_stuff'

res1 = [y for y in re.split(r'\(([^\(]*)\)', strs) if y <> ' ']
print res1
```